# issue with nested python module importing when executing imported function itself

Tags: python, import, module, path

I believe this question must have already been asked but I cannot find an explanation for my problem, sorry if it is a duplicate.

```
Folder
├── Generator.py
└── modules
    ├── Function1.py
    └── Subfunction.py
```

Generator.py imports Function1, and Function1 imports Subfunction.
Function1 must be able to be run as a standalone program and as an imported module of Generator.py

It is not a problem itself, as I am using the *if __ name__ == "__ main__":* to recognize the call type.
But the program fails on importing Subfunction depending on the code I am executing.

```
# Generator.py
    import Function1

# Function1.py
    import Subfunction
    import modules.Subfunction
```

The first one works if I execute Function1.py, but it fails if I run Generator.py

The second one works if I execute Generator.py, but it fails if I run Function1.py

I thought imports and relative paths are related to the module where the code is placed, not from a perspective of the top-caller. I tried *import .modules.Function1* and *import .Function1* but the issue remains.
Is there any elegant way to import Subfunction for both uses, or do I need to include import under if *name == main* or trap it in *try/except*?

**Edit: all code for @Bastien B**

In this shape it works if I execute Function1.py itself.
If I execute Generator.py, I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Function1'

```
# Generator.py
    import Function1
    print(Function1.Function1_return)

# Function1.py
    def Function1_return():
        return Subfunction.Subfunction_return()
    import Subfunction
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(Function1_return())

# Subfunction.py
    def Subfunction_return():
        return "this is subfunction"
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the code of your 3 files ?

Comment: @BastienB included in Edit

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see your 'if **name** ...' is not the problem.

If you use a local venv this should work just fine:

> generator.py

```py
from Folder.modules.function1 import Function1_return
print(Function1_return())
```

> Function1.py

```py
from Folder.modules.Subfunction import Subfunction_return

def Function1_return():
    return Subfunction_return()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Function1_return())
```

> Subfunction.py

```py
def Subfunction_return():
    return "this is subfunction"
```

Depending of your files structure you may have to tweak this a beat